# eclipse exe not running in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I was using eclipse in my ubuntu 12.04. How i run my eclipse is, double click on eclipse exe and then do my application in that eclipse IDE. Unfortunately i lost my eclipse folder(which is unziped from downloaded) and temp(which is i saved all projects). But i had that unziped folder backup so i tried to past and tried to open eclipse exe but nothing happen.

Note : I have installed wine software.So long i was open with wine only but now nothing happen when open with wine.

Note 2:This maybe silly question but i want  to know why this happen and i must fix this without install new one.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: that's a linux gtk executable, not a windows one. just double click it after checking it has execute permissions

Comment: @guido Sorry i dont understand you "just double click it after checking it has execute permissions".?

Comment: @guido hey i understood you and got fix this.Actually i did not select property -> permission -> select Allow executing file as program.